# Specify struct name in typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What is the difference between:

```
typedef struct{

    uint8   index;
    uint8   data[256];

}list_t;

list_t myList;
```

and

```
typedef struct list_t{

    uint8   index;
    uint8   data[256];

}list_t;

list_t myList;
```

I am using the first approach but I saw the second one on an answer. I just want to define type and define the variable with that type separately.

Comment: NB: POSIX reserves identifiers ending with `_t`.

Comment: @Alnitak What does that mean?

Comment: It means that if you're developing code to compile on a POSIX compatible platform you should use that suffix for your own type names.

Comment: Oops, I meant "should *not* " !

Comment: I was literally thinking that 'why did he mention that if I can already use it for my own type names' lol :) Now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be matter of taste and preferred codding style, but the second way (as mentioned in other answers) is useful for self-referencing structures (e.g. list or tree data structures) and forward declaration.
As for me I prefer the second way in C and think that it is much more common.

[Reference](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/struct/declare.html)

In C:

```
[typedef] struct [struct_name]
{
    type attribute;
    type attribute2;
    // ...
    [struct struct_name *struct_instance;]
} [struct_name_t] [struct_instance];
```

In this case, there are two options: the first is to omit both `typedef` and `struct_name_t`, in which case to declare a struct you will need to actually include the `struct` keyword:

```
struct struct_name struct_instance;
```

Or you can use a `typedef` to declare a struct_name_t type that you can use:

```
struct_name_t struct_instance;
```

In either case, if you wish to declare a pointer to a struct inside of the struct, you must use the first syntax, with the keyword struct:

```
struct struct_name *struct_instance;
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is useful for self-referencing data structures.

```
typedef struct
{
  int value;
  Example1 *ptr; // error here: the type Example1 is not known yet
} Example1;

typedef struct Example2
{
  int value;
  struct Example2 *ptr; // OK: the type struct Example2 is known
} Example2;
```

Note that the name after `struct` is not necessarily the same as the one used for `typedef`.

Comment: thanks +1 but .. is `struct` keyword is necessary in `struct Example2 *ptr;`?

Comment: @snr yes because, at this point of the analysis (`ptr` member) by the compiler, the type `struct Example2` is known (partially, as a forward declaration) but not the type `Example2` (typedef) ; this latter will be known at the last semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach allows you to forward declare the structure type. So if we are dealing with headers, you can avoid a needless transitive inclusion. For example, consider this small header:

```
// No need to include the header with the full struct definition
// A forward declaration will do
struct list_t;
void foo(struct list_t *);
void bar(void); // Doesn't use list_t
```

Which removes the dependency on `list_t`'s full definition for all client code. Code that needs to use only `bar` isn't forced to include the definition of `list_t` (by transitive inclusion).

When you use the first approach, you create an alias to a struct type with no tag, so you *can't* forward declare it. And client code is *forced* to include your type definition to have access to its name.